# How to handle exceptions using Spring Webclient's synchronous call?

Tags: java, spring, exception, spring-webflux

I've created a service class to make an API call:

```
ServiceA {
  public B sendReceive(Request req) {
    return Optional.of(req).map(this::transform).map(apiService::call);
  }
  private ApiRequest transform(Request req) {
    ...
  }
}

ApiService {
  public B call(ApiRequest req) {
    return webClient.post().bodyValue(req).bodyToMono().block();
  }

@ControllerAdvice
ExceptionManager {
  @ExceptionHandler(Exception.class)
  public ResponseEntity handle(Exception ex) {
    ...
  }
}
```

I tried to produce an exception in the `transform` method to test the ControllerAdvice class, but it does not work. The exception goes directly into `InvocableHandlerMethod` class instead of ExceptionManager class, which is inside the reactive package.

Since I'm not using any `Mono`/`Flux`, the typical `.onError` will not work for my case.

How do I make the ControllerAdvice working? Or how should I handle exception in the blocking call?

Comment: Could you please clarify where exactly the exception is thrown, what kind of exception and add the controller advice code that is supposed to catch this exception + add a stacktrace of what actually happens

Comment: as the previous commenter, this is way too little information for us to even start answering.

Comment: I think this might help you to solve the problem, I'll quote a  spring's Github` post.One could argue that since a @ControllerAdvice can be restricted to a subset of Controllers, then you need to select a controller handler in the first place`  [Using Controller Advice with WebFlux](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/issues/21097)

Comment: I have an exceptionhandler to catch ‘Exception.class’. For testing purpose I throw a’NullPointerException’ in my transform method.

Comment: still too little information, we need your project structure, we need to see more of the implementation. Please produce a minimal example that shows your problem so that we can try it out for ourselves.